# Disadvantages for virtual product?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, simple-product, virtual-products

I understood that for Magento2 configurable products the associated products are created as **virtual** products instead of **simple** products, when weight is not given.

But **is there any disadvantages for this?** What would be different if I give weight for those virtual products and make them simple products?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no major disadvantage of that.

But main concept  is if product has a weight then you need to **deliver it physically**.

If product has no weight that means its virtual product **(Something which we don't need to deliver it but we can download it or get the details of it from the website only)**

Suppose you have T-Shirt (Configurable Product) - Now all colors and sizes of t-shirt must have weight. If you select no weight option here
then what would you be delivered ?, as its physical product.

But when delivery/shipping is depended on weight then it makes you in trouble/disadvantage. That time even though its configurable product
still you need to mention product has weight.

Refer this link for more details (**things to remember**) - http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-virtual.html

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Happy to help keep helping :)